# mongoose discriminator find query

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to use a test case as described in  ["mongoose-schema-extend"](https://www.npmjs.org/package/mongoose-schema-extend)

All is working just as explained there.

But, I would expect it to give me the ability to do a search query on the inherited type.
So if we consider the example showed in the link above:

```
var VehicleSchema = mongoose.Schema({ 
  make : String,
}, { collection : 'vehicles', discriminatorKey : '_type' });

var CarSchema = VehicleSchema.extend({
  year : Number
});
var BusSchema = VehicleSchema.extend({
  route : Number
})

var Vehicle = mongoose.model('vehicle', VehicleSchema),
    Car = mongoose.model('car', CarSchema),
    Bus = mongoose.model('bus', BusSchema);

var accord = new Car({ 
  make : 'Honda',
  year : 1999
});
var muni = new Bus({
  make : 'Neoplan',
  route : 33
});
```

I would expect `Car.find({})` to return only the documents which have `_type : Car`. Instead, I get all `vehicles`.

Is there a way to get only the `cars` except for doing `Car.find{"_type":"Car"})`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have to do a feature request for that to the package owner or do a pull request to the project yourself. A work-around, however, could be to implement a custom find method:

```
CarSchema.statics._find = function(query, next) {
    query._type = 'Car';
    this.find(query, next);
}

Car._find({}, function(err, cars) {
    ... 
};
```

The _find should now only return Car objects.

Comment: The discriminator key, is a feature supported by Mongoose (yet not documented at all). The question is if there is a built-in way to do the query. If not then I guess the package owner can't really help us...

Comment: @skme how did you end up solving this?

Comment: No solution in sight.. you can use what @materik suggested... Posted issue in github but still no answer

Comment: Update : the issue is in development : https://github.com/briankircho/mongoose-schema-extend/issues/26